# How to have a scrollable Dialog using PrimeFaces

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, dialog

Hi Everybody i m looking for a way to have a scrollable dialog (a dialog which moves with the scrollbar) it will be perfect for my page and thank you i have searched about it and did not find what i want ^^'

Comment: How about using a [overlayPanel](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/overlayPanel.xhtml)? Looks definetly "scrollable"

Comment: If by scrollable you mean that it has scroll bar then i did that by fixing the height and width of the dialog box so it had scroll bars

Comment: @LarsBauer non what i want is a panel grid which can move by itself when the scrollbar moves down he will moves down too ^^ and when you return the top it will be in his position ^^ ( i dont know if its clear but there is an example of what i need http://desgeeksetdeslettres.com/programmation-java/menu-fixe-mais-flottant-selon-la-scrollbar-js-css) look at the menu on the left ^^

Comment: @anas no anas its not what i want look at my previous comment and thank you ^^

Comment: i went on the internet and found a quick solution i havent tested it myself yet but you can try `style="repeat scroll 0% 0%;"` try this in the scroll bar.

Comment: i have already did it , look at this site if someone is interested http://desgeeksetdeslettres.com/programmation-java/menu-fixe-mais-flottant-selon-la-scrollbar-js-css